# Is there any functionality in JPA which would mirror a non existent @PreCascadePersist functionality

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to Persist an object A which has fields b and c which are marked as Cascade All. What I want to do is to be able to run a pre-defined method when b and c are being persisted because A is getting persisted.

A @PrePersist won't work, because I want this method to only kick in - in case b and c are getting persisted through a Cascade operation on A. If b and c are getting persisted independently, I do not wish to run this line of code.

example:

```
@Entity
public class A{

    @Id;  
    Long id;         

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="a",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    B b;

}

@Entity
public class B{

    @Id
    Long id;

    String field;

    boolean isCascaded;

}
```

So here what i want is to mark each individual object of Class B which was cascaded through A and not independently to have the field

> isCascaded

stored as 'true'. I can't use a @PrePersist since that will always be called irrespective of whether B is getting persisted through a cascade operation or independently.

Comment: Can you add some code? It's hard to understand now.